# Reducing a gift cards array

Tags: javascript

In an eCommerce site I'm building, I allow users to manage gift cards, each user who purchases a gift card, gets a gift card object pushed into a database. For example, a user would have a bunch of gift cards like so:

```
const giftcards = [
  {amount: 20, id: 1, ....}, 
  {amount: 23, id: 2, ...}
 ]
```

Now at checkout, if the sum of the `giftcards` amount is greater than the total price (at checkout), I would like to loop through the `giftcards` array and subtract the amount or remove the gift card if the price of the cost is greater than one `giftcard`, then continue the process until the amount paid by the gift cards are equal, and of course, save a new copy of the edited gift card array

```
For example, if the total were to be
const total = 40
```

Then the new `giftcards` array should look like:

```
const giftcards = [
  {amount: 3, id: 2, ...}
 ]
```

EDIT:

```
 function reduceGiftCards(amount) {
 for(let i = 0; i < giftcards.length; i++) {
   if(amount > giftcards[i].amount) {
     giftcards[i].amount = 0
     amount = amount - giftcards[i].amount
   }
 }
 console.log(giftcards)
 }
    reduceGiftCards(40)
```

//when logged, all gift cards are given a value of 0

Comment: What have you go so far for the loop?

Comment: Is there a particular order you would like the gift cards to be used?

Comment: from top to bottom, I'm trying to use for loop/for each, but its not going as expected, finding it hard.

Comment: If you can add your code and where you are having issues with it people will be able to more easily provide help

Comment: I've edited my post

Answer (score 0):

These two lines need to be reversed in order

```
giftcards[i].amount = 0
amount = amount - giftcards[i].amount
```

Here the second part is always 0 and your amount remains the same throughout.

```
function reduceGiftCards(amount) {

    for (let i = 0; i < giftcards.length; i++) {
        if (amount = 0) break;
        if (amount >= giftcards[i].amount) {
            amount = amount - giftcards[i].amount;
            giftcards[i].amount = 0; // or remove it?
        }else{
            giftcards[i].amount = giftcards[i].amount - amount;
            amount = 0;
        }
        
    }
    // remove all giftcards whose amount is 0
    giftcards = giftcards.filter(item => item.amount !== 0);
    console.log(giftcards);
}
reduceGiftCards(40);
```

Comment: Yea, remove all gift cards whose amount = 0, also, if there is remaining an amount, it should continue to substract the amount from the next gift cards

Comment: Updated the answer.